# Windows 8.1 PC can't communicate with BT Home Hub 5 over wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, home-hub

I have a BT Home Hub 5 modem/router on an ADSL connection. I'm having trouble getting my Windows 8.1 machine to connect to the network properly over wifi.

My PC is correctly assigned an IP address by the router, and appears correctly in the router's settings. However, it fails to communicate with the rest of the network.

I have tested different devices and combinations, and these are the results:

What works:

- WAN internet connection to Home Hub 5
- Wired connections to Home Hub 5 (all devices)
- Wireless connections between Home Hub 5 and Linux, OS X & Android
  devices
- Wireless connections between Win 8 PC and other networks

What doesn't work:

- Wireless connection between Win 8 PC and Home Hub 5

Clearly there is some conflict here specifically between Win 8/the NIC and the Home Hub.

- Pings etc. result in destination host unreachable
- Flushing/releasing/renewing the DNS cache doesn't help, and ipconfig
  /renew yields an error "DHCP server unreachable"
- Resetting the TCP/IP stack with netsh doesn't help
- Disabling IPv6 on the PC's wifi card doesn't help
- Disabling firewall doesn't help

I'm at a total loss here! Can anyone help?

Cheers.

Comment: Have you updated your wireless card drivers/software? Have you tried "repair" on the wireless connection?

Comment: Post ipconfig /all on Win 8 PC (don't forget to cleanse the MAC addresses), post IP address of the Home Hub, post netstat -rn on Win 8 PC.